# Search in TStrings

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How can I check if a particular string exists in a TStrings ? For example I have TStrings which contain a lot of text and I want to check if string "Hello!" is present in this text.

"Hello!" is just an example string. It can be anything. String can be in between other strings like "something Hello! something"

Comment: Do you want to be able to find "Hello!" as part of a phrase, e.g. if "Hello! World", or "Hi, Hello!" is in the list, or only if "Hello!" is the only word?

Comment: Hello! is just an example string.. Any string.

Comment: I mean to you want to find if the search phrase is a substring of one of the strings in the `TStrings.Strings` property

Comment: You really need to be more clear with your question. This one is vague, because you've not explained whether you want to find an individual line containing certain text or whether you want to find certain text anywhere in the contents of the `TStrings`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the pos function on the TStrings text property:

```
if pos('Hello!', strings.text) > 0 then
begin
end
```

This will find the string if it occurs anywhere in the TStrings. To find the string in which it occurs you would need to iterate through the strings applying the pos function on each of them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the IndexOf function of TStrings

```
if Strings.IndexOf('Hello')<>-1 then
    caption:='Found';
```

This function return -1 if the string was not found,
else it returns the index of this string in the TStrings;

Comment: Won't work for what Santos needs, which is finding if the given text is found *anywhere* within any of the lines of text, even if it's just a portion of one line. This method assumes the entire line matches the given text.

Comment: In C++, this helped me determine if a TStrings list from a TComboBox->Items exactly contains a given string. Thank you!